# Half-installed kernel, can't install/uninstall anything

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel, dpkg

Well, I have this problem which I am not sure how I got, but I need some help.

First of all, my computer runs the Ubuntu version 14.04.3 LTS, and the current kernel (the one I get from `uname -r`) is 3.13.0-63-generic. Please tell me if you need to know anything else.

My problem is the following: every time I try to install/uninstall some package, either with apt-get or Synaptic, I get an error about these packages:

- linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic
- linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
- linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic

The output (for example, when I run `sudo apt-get install 'package-name'`) I get is:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (3.13.0-65.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency (3.13.0-65.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried some solutions online but, thus far, none has solved my problem. Some of them (and respective output) are these:

Input: `sudo apt-get -f install`

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (3.13.0-65.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency (3.13.0-65.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Input: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Output:

```
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency (3.13.0-65.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
) points to /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
 (/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-lowlatency) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
 (/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-65-lowlatency /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (3.13.0-65.106) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-65-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-65-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic.postinst line 1025.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic depends on linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-lowlatency
 linux-image-3.13.0-65-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-65-generic
```

If there are any other info that you need, I am happy to give you.

If anyone could help me, that would mean everything to me. I really need to be able to install/uninstall packages in my machine, so I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.

PS: please bear in mind that I am no Ubuntu/Linux expert.

EDIT:

Here is the content of /etc/default/grub.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows Boot UEFI loader"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="60"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
```

Comment: take a look at your `/etc/default/grub` is it corrupted?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: @A.B. Ay! that was my idea!

Comment: @LittleByBlue A.B. I already edited the post, you can check above the content of /etc/default/grub :)

Comment: No, I only edited my post, not the file! I only copied the content of that file, as you can check above. Sorry for the misunderstanding, my bad, should have expressed myself better.

Comment: see your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` delete the first `"`.

Comment: @LittleByBlue I don't understand, should I comment that line?

Comment: @LittleByBlue A.B. Thank you so much for such a quick answer :)

I have a question, though: now, when I do `uname -r` I get `3.13.0-65-lowlatency`. Is it normal? (the 'lowlatency' part, I mean). I had never seen such kernel, only the ones finishing with 'generic'.

Comment: @Serg has answered me in one of the answers, so nevermind my last question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line in the error messages

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 37: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

says, you have an error in line 37, but you don't have a line 37. Therefore, the most likely explanation is that you have a quotation error. And now have a look at this line, taken from your question:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"
```

You have three double quotes in this line. Remove one double quote:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"
```

and don't forget the

```
sudo update-grub
```

after editing the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, IT WORKS! :D
I have been trying some stuff that previously didn't work, and everything is running great now!

Comment: I have a question, though: now, when I do `uname -r` I get `3.13.0-65-lowlatency`. Is it normal? (the 'lowlatency' part, I mean). I had never seen such kernel, only the ones finishing with 'generic'.

Comment: Nice. If the answer solved your problem, accept the answer by a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: @EDias From [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel):lowlatency kernel - very similar to the -preempt kernel and based on the -generic kernel source tree, but uses a more aggressive configuration to further reduce latency. Also known as a soft real-time kernel.

Comment: @Serg Thanks very much for your answer :) I'm no expert, but I assume it means that there is nothing wrong with my kernel, which is perfect for me! Thanks everyone, it's working great now!

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your `/etc/default/grub`.

The line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"
```

has to be

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable i915.lvds_downclock=1 drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 i915_enable_rc6=1 i915_enable_fbc=1"
```

as the first would produce a semantic error.

Comment: Thank you very much, IT WORKS! :D

I have a question, though: now, when I do `uname -r` I get `3.13.0-65-lowlatency`. Is it normal? (the 'lowlatency' part, I mean). I had never seen such kernel, only the ones finishing with 'generic'.

Comment: Well, @Serg has answered me in the other answer, but thanks anyway :)